# angularjs - unable to call same directive from different pages

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I'm working on an app that needs to have the same directive on each page.
Unfortunately, it is not working as expected.

Let's say I open the app and visit page with **ID=1**

The page with ID=1 loads, I click on the directive, and everything works as expected.

Now, I change page and I go to page with **ID=2**

Like before, the page loads and I click on 'directive' but nothing happens.

If now I go back to page with **ID=1**, the directive is opened in that page.

Basically, I thought that changing page was enough for the directive to be re-rendered on the new page, but apparently it is not.

**index.html:**

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

**directive.coffee:**

```
angular.module('myApp', [ 'ionic' ]).directive 'myDirective', ->
  {
  restrict: 'E'
  scope:
    mode: '@mode'
  replace: true
  templateUrl: 'templates/template.html'
  }
```

I've created a pen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Xdqrve?editors=1010

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem with similar checkbox `name` and label `for` values.

You have to change `mode` parameter like this:

`<mode-selector mode="1"></mode-selector>
 <mode-selector mode="2"></mode-selector>
 <mode-selector mode="3"></mode-selector>`

And append `mode` at checkbox name & label id:

```
<input type="checkbox" href="#" class="menu-open" name="menu-open-{{mode}}" id="menu-open-{{mode}}"/>
<label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open-{{mode}}">
    <i class="zone-details-current-mode icon-mode-{{mode}}"></i>
    <span class="hamburger hamburger-1"></span>
    <span class="hamburger hamburger-2"></span>
    <span class="hamburger hamburger-3"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved my issue. I used ID instead of mode as I will definitely have same modes while ID is unique. Thanks again